# Why class definition needs more information of its attributes than what is needed in a function definition?

Tags: python, class, scope, namespaces

```
def myfunc():
    return x
x = 10
print(myfunc())
```

The above codes work, where the free variable `x` does not need to be defined when I define `myfunc`.

However, the following codes do not work:

```
class myclass:
   func = extfunc

def extfunc(self):
    return 'hello'
```

Here I need to move the definition of `extfunc` before the class definition, in order to make the codes work.

Why does class definition need more information of its attributes than what is needed for a free variable in a function definition?

Comment: Because the body of the function is evaluated when called, but the body of the class definition is evaluated at class definition time, because how else would you define the class?

Comment: Is it possible that there exist languages in which the class definition can be flexible enough so that it does not require the class definition to be fully determined until a class instance is instantiated?

Comment: How would you be able to define class attributes and methods then? You *can* basically do that by moving stuff into `__init__`, but that’s inefficient for each instance to have its own version of a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
def myfunc():
    return x
```

defines a function, but doesn't **execute** the code inside it where `x` is until/unless `myfunc` is called. The *body* of the function isn't evaluated when the function definition is evaluated, it's evaluated *later* when the function is called.

In contrast, in this code:

```
class myclass:
    func = extfunc
```

the class definition is evaluated in order to create the class, as described in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax). So `func = extfunc` is evaluated as part of class definition in order to assign a value to the `func` variable in the class scope. `func` is like a static member in languages that use that terminology.

A more direct comparison would be this:

```
class myclass:
    def example(self):
        return x
```

There, `return x` isn't evaluated until or unless `example` is called.

See also [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) in the documentation:

> *Attribute references* use the standard syntax used for all attribute references in Python: `obj.name`. Valid attribute names are all the names that were in the class’s namespace when the class object was created. So, if the class definition looked like this:
>
> ```
> class MyClass:
>     """A simple example class"""
>     i = 12345
>
>     def f(self):
>         return 'hello world'
> ```
>
> then `MyClass.i` and `MyClass.f` are valid attribute references, returning an integer and a function object, respectively.

In your example, `myclass.func` would be a valid reference immediately after the class definition, so `func = extfunc` must be evaluated *during* the class definition, unlike the body of a function.